# 2012 Ford F-150 Rust

Tags: ford, rust, f-150

I have a 2012 Ford F-150 that's starting to show a bit of rust, primarily on the front and rear bumpers and then on the undercarriage of the body below the doors.

[image: front bumper]
[image: front bumper 2]
[image: between door and bed]
[image: rear bumper]
[image: rear bumper 2]
[image: under carriage]

I have a few questions on this:

1. Are there any recommendations to either inhibit the further spread of this rust or remove it altogether?
2. Ideally, I'd like to keep a hold of this truck for another 2 years before trading in, but in that span how much worse can this rust expect to get?

Live in the Upper Midwest of the U.S. so snow/ice/sand/salt comes into play in the winter months.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

The rust will inevitably get worse unless it is removed (sanding) and the metal sealed with paint.  The main area to be concerned with is under the rocker panel, the metal there is much thinner than the metal on the bumper, and that's where the holes will develop.  You've got years worth of use before holes develop in the bumper.  I'm in the upper midwest and have had a few nicks in the front bumper of my truck like this rusting for several years now with no visible worsening.  When it appears on other body panels I hop on it right away.